# Android Dashboard Pattern

Tags: android, layout, dashboard

In Tim Bray's latest Android [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) he mentions the "dashboard" ui pattern (what is used for the Twitter app, Facebook app, etc.  Is this layout as simple as a GridView with Buttons or is it something else?

**Update:**

The [DashboardLayout](https://gist.github.com/882650) was released by Roman Nurik last night. It is a derivative of the layout used in the Google IO 2010 app.

Comment: The Twitter application will be released as open source sometime, as noted in that blog post. Until then, it is going to be difficult for us to tell how it is implemented.

Comment: Does any one have a solution for a Dashboard with Drag and Drop of Views inside the dashboard with self re-organization of children & thumbnail of the view appearing on drag ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best example you can use is from the Google I/O 2011 Android App. They implement all those design patterns in their app. You can find the code at the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml?r=27a82ff10b436da5914a3961df245ff8f66b6252

The 2011 version uses a custom layout called 'DashboardLayout' in a fragment which gets shared in phone and tablet specific layouts. The logic in DashboardLayout is responsible for all the auto layout magic!

Comment: The dashboard layout didn't work for me. It put all of the icons one above the other. It happens When I use it in another layout element. Perhaps the calculation have trouble with an outer layout?

Comment: I have the same problem when the dashboard is the root element.

Answer (score 25):

Code of DashboardLayout from IO 2010 app was rather buggy. But Roman Nurik has fixed it and now it's possible to use DashboardLayout easily in your app.

Howto:

1. Add [this class](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java?r=27a82ff10b436da5914a3961df245ff8f66b6252) into your project
2. In your layout, just drop couple of buttons inside DashboardLayout, similar [like here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml?r=27a82ff10b436da5914a3961df245ff8f66b6252).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve a similar dashboard using a relative layout. Its still a work in progress, so your mileage may vary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lay_action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/label_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50px"

            android:text="@string/app_title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/lay_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/lay_action"
        android:paddingTop="25px"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button1" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button2" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/button1"
            android:text="@string/button3"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button3" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@id/button2"
            android:text="@string/button4"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

The Dashboard layout did not work for me, thus I suggest a layout based solution.
It's just a bunch of layouts within layouts.

The key is the relativity of weights between the spacing layouts and the content layouts.

You can very simply move icons and define other layouts for bigger or lighter dashboards.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: portrait]

And here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_vertical" >

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_vertical" >

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_vertical" >

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/dashboard_textview"
                android:text="Text 6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout style="@style/dashboard_space_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the styles:

```
<resources>
<style name="dashboard_space_vertical">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>

<style name="dashboard_content_vertical">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">3</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="dashboard_space_horizontal">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">2</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:background">@color/black</item> -->
</style>

<style name="dashboard_content_horizontal">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">3</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="dashboard_imageview">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>

<style name="dashboard_textview">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dashboard_thumbnail_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps someone. Enjoy.

Comment: I use it by using an include: <include layout="@layout/dashboard" />

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be implemented with a TableLayout containing Image- and TextViews.

Comment: Can you please post an example or a link to a good example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the best and the simplest way of creating Dashboard..

very nicely explained

[How To Build A Dashboard User Interface In Android](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/build-dashboard-ui-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

romannurik posted recently a custom `ViewGroup` to do this. The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/882650).

Comment: The code is no longer maintained in github. See comment: **/*
 * ATTENTION:
 *
 * This layout is now maintained in the `iosched' code.google.com project:
 *
 * http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java
 *
 */**

Comment: @kilaka: Your link is dead

Comment: @AbdulRahman: they changed the code. The dashboard if no longer used. Look at the history - you'll find the code there.