# Android Dash Board

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a dashboard like the twitters application.but i am unable to set the buttons location and i dont know how to change the image of the button on click or move.I want the dash board like this Image:

[image]
So please provide me the solution.

Comment: what you have already tried? Show your code please.

Comment: Linear layouts with weights will do it.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873568/android-dashboard-pattern

Answer (score 0):

For my dashboard, I'm using a RelativeLayout with a TableLayout inside it. I use ImageViews for the 'buttons' and set an OnClickListener to each which starts an Activity for each one.