# issue on Screen design with table layout under scroll layout.

Tags: android

I have seen an issue while designing dashboard screen,
I had one layout : say Linearlayout1 and having scroll layout: say scrollLayout1 as child of Linearlayout1, and havinf Table layout under this scroll layout,
i added table rows which contains buttons with drawables.
now the question is> I can see, table layout height is bit more than the scroll layout  which is child of scroll layout.  how child layout can have more height then parent layout. (I set table layout height as matchparent or fill parent).

Comment: So the table view is the child of the scroll view?

Comment: Yes tableLayout is the child of scroll view

Comment: So why do you need to scroll view? :)

Comment: Thanks soham, will post more info, after Location session :)

Comment: chk http://www.technotalkative.com/android-dashboard-design-pattern-implementation/ for best in any screen density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a dashboard, then use the DashboardLayout from Google IO open source app.
That is the best way to do it. If you are planning to do something manually, it may not be possible to test on all the screen sizes, densities.

I used it in 3 of my projects, which just works.

Check [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055775/314256).

Comment: Even Facebook uses Google IO dashboard. Explained here: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try This it may helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   

    <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/toplayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dip">
            <TextView 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
             android:text="TopBar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView 
          android:id="@+id/scrolllayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="150dip"
          android:padding="5dip"
          >
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Open..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Save..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-S"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Save As..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-Shift-S"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Import..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Export..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-E"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```