# Custom ListView defined in XML (so without a programatically defined custom adapter)

Tags: android

The main menu of my app is a list of items that has a very specific look. It has a custom divider and every list element has a custom colour and height. To achieve this is have built a custom ArrayAdapter, but I wonder whether this is really necessary. The buttons in the main menu are always the same, so I wonder what's the better design pattern here. Pure XML or overriding the ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a "Custom ListView for main menu purely in XML not using a programatically defined custom adapter". `ListView` requires a `ListAdapter`, whether you like it or not.

That being said, I would not put "buttons" in a `ListView` in the first place. Ideally, you would not even have a "main menu of [your] app", but rather would take the user someplace useful when they launch it. If you are sure that you need to have an activity that is a "main menu", use the dashboard pattern: [Android Dashboard Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873568/android-dashboard-pattern)

Comment: Great tips, but I really need to stick to the design and the design looks like a list. ListView it is, then?

Comment: @Maarten: "ListView it is, then?" -- that is up to you. If you do use a `ListView`, you need a `ListAdapter`.