# Are these GridView in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

I want to make an app with a interface like google+ or evernote like the following , how to perform these ui? Use GridView in Android?

Comment: below link can help you http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are similar to that. But they have their own term called **DashBoard**.

Here is a link on a tutorial,

[DashBoard..](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2011%2F12%2Fandroid-dashboard-design-tutorial%2F&ei=qHM3UMGxAcb4rQeAiYFA&usg=AFQjCNGfhlP04wHNwbu8FRde-xWeNhKCdQ)

Here is a link which explains few things to you,

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

And also this question here, which was previously discussed about it,

[Android Dashboard Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2873568/603744)

And this looks to be the suggested way to do it,

```
<com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.widget.DashboardLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_schedule"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_schedule"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_schedule" />
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_map"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_map"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_map" />
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_sessions"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_sessions"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_sessions" />
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_starred"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_starred"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_starred" />
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_vendors"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_vendors"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_vendors" />
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_announcements"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_announcements"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_announcements" />
```

[Taken From Here..](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml?r=27a82ff10b436da5914a3961df245ff8f66b6252)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity
    implements OnItemClickListener {
Context con;
static LauncherIcon[] ICONS = {
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.breakfasdd, "text1"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.lunch, "text2"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.dinner1, "text3"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.syn1, "text4"),

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

static class LauncherIcon {
    final String text;
    final int imgId;

    public LauncherIcon(int imgId, String text) {
        super();
        this.imgId = imgId;
        this.text = text;
    }

}

static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ICONS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public LauncherIcon getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_icon, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.dashboard_icon_text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.dashboard_icon_img);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.setImageResource(ICONS[position].imgId);
        holder.text.setText(ICONS[position].text);

        return v;

    }
}
```

and to get item selected

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        int pos = position;{
}
```

dashboard_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_icon_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="96.0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_icon_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

dashboard.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BACK" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
        style="@style/dashboard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20.0dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```